# Room 2.1 SQLite FTS: inserting new single FTS object in database

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-room, fts4

I have been trying to use new Android's Room 2.1 feature of FTS table to enable search functionality.

**Entity:**

```
 @Entity
    class ChatMessageEntity(
            @PrimaryKey
            var messageId: String,
            var messageUser: String,
            var messageText: String,
            )
```

**FTS entity:**

```
@Fts4(contentEntity = ChatMessageEntity::class)
@Entity
class ChatMessageFts(
        var messageText: String //only want messageText searchable
)
```

**Database:**

```
@Database(entities = [ChatMessageEntity::class, ChatMessageFts::class], version = 1)
abstract class ChatMessageDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun chatMessageDatabase(): ChatMessageDao

    companion object {
        fun create(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(context, ChatMessageDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME).build()
    }
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Query("INSERT INTO ChatMessageFts(ChatMessageFts) VALUES('rebuild')") //works
    suspend fun ftsRebuild()

@Query("INSERT INTO ChatMessageFts(docid, messageText) VALUES(:id, :text)") //compiles but doesn't work
    suspend fun saveFtsMessage(id: Long, text: String)
```

I wish to add each row in FTS when I also add the row in the original table (ChatMessageEntity - not shown). When rebuilding the FTS table from scratch, it works perfectly (`ftsRebuild()` above).

However, I wish to add each input individually. I have tried many things (for example `saveFtsMessage()` shown above) - adding without docId, trying with rowId, ... I even tried adding a new object `ChatMessageEntity` into `ChatMessageFts` as input but I didn't manage to compile it due to errors.

Any suggestion on how I can add individual input in FTS table is most welcome!

Comment: You should not need either of those `INSERT INTO ChatMessageFts` statements. Inserting into `ChatMessage` will populate `ChatMessageFts` via triggers.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you sooo much. Don't know how I didn't realise this before. Do you think I should close this question or mark your answer as accepted (if so please add it below)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Fts4(contentEntity = ChatMessageEntity::class)
```

The magic of the `contentEntity` property of the annotation is that Room sets up triggers to keep your FTS table in sync with the corresponding entity table:

```
"contentSyncTriggers": [
  "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_paragraphsFts_BEFORE_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON `paragraphs` BEGIN DELETE FROM `paragraphsFts` WHERE `docid`=OLD.`rowid`; END",
  "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_paragraphsFts_BEFORE_DELETE BEFORE DELETE ON `paragraphs` BEGIN DELETE FROM `paragraphsFts` WHERE `docid`=OLD.`rowid`; END",
  "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_paragraphsFts_AFTER_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON `paragraphs` BEGIN INSERT INTO `paragraphsFts`(`docid`, `prose`) VALUES (NEW.`rowid`, NEW.`prose`); END",
  "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS room_fts_content_sync_paragraphsFts_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON `paragraphs` BEGIN INSERT INTO `paragraphsFts`(`docid`, `prose`) VALUES (NEW.`rowid`, NEW.`prose`); END"
]
```

(from [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.2/FTS) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Room))

So long as you are inserting, updating, and deleting your entities, the FTS table will be maintained automatically. You just use the FTS table for querying purposes.

If you skip the `contentEntity` annotation — and assuming that works — then you might need to maintain your FTS table independently.